# React: Using a same component twice in a page removes the data in first component

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I have two tabs in my react app with each tab having a spreadsheet.

I have called the same spreadsheet tag in both the tabs. when i enter data in the first tab and move to second tab, the data in the second tab is getting replaced with the default value which i am setting in the useState.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Tabs from '@mui/material/Tabs';
import Tab from '@mui/material/Tab';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';

import Spreadsheet from './components/Spreadsheet.js'

function TabPanel(props) {
  const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <div
      role="tabpanel"
      hidden={value !== index}
      id={`simple-tabpanel-${index}`}
      aria-labelledby={`simple-tab-${index}`}
      {...other}
    >
      {value === index && (
        <Box sx={{ p: 3 }}>
          <Typography>{children}</Typography>
        </Box>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

TabPanel.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node,
  index: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  value: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
};

function a11yProps(index) {
  return {
    id: `simple-tab-${index}`,
    'aria-controls': `simple-tabpanel-${index}`,
  };
}

export default function BasicTabs() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
      <Box sx={{ borderBottom: 1, borderColor: 'divider' }}>
        <Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange} aria-label="basic tabs example">
          <Tab label="Item One" {...a11yProps(0)} />
          <Tab label="Item Two" {...a11yProps(1)} />
          <Tab label="Item Three" {...a11yProps(2)} />
        </Tabs>
      </Box>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
        Item One
        <div id='div_spreadsheet1'>
          <Spreadsheet id="spreadsheet1"> </Spreadsheet>
        </div>
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
        Item Two
        <div id='div_spreadsheet12'>
          <Spreadsheet id="spreadsheet2"> </Spreadsheet>
        </div>
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={2}>
        Item Three
      </TabPanel>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

**EDIT:**

Adding the Spreadsheet.js code

```
import Spreadsheet from "react-spreadsheet";
import { useState } from "react";
  
export default function Sheet(){
  const [data, setData] = useState([
    [{ value: "" }, { value: "1" }],
  ]);
  return(
  <div>
    <h4>SpreadSheet</h4>
    <Spreadsheet data={data} onChange={setData} />
  </div> 
  )
    
};
```

How to restrict this from happening. Please help.

Comment: Can you please add the Spreadsheet component code as well?

Comment: Hi @Anu, I have updated the above question with Spreadsheet component

Comment: Hi, I see that in Spreadsheet.js you have a custom component called Sheet but it was not used in the BasicTabs. But it is using react-spreadsheet component directly without passing any data to it. Is this intended?